# text box read only

Tags: c#, .net, textbox

i create form with TextBox on it. Text box have a ReadOnly true propertiy. when i add text to text box. all text inside the text box is selected. how i can rid that. i tried to change value of SelectionLength, SelectionStart, SelectedText properties but that did not help.
I Use VC# 2008 express.

Comment: How are you adding text to your text box? Its hard to help without more information.

Comment: textBox1.Text += "String" + Environment.NewLine + "String";

Comment: If the text is selected, you are probably selecting it somehow in your code. Remove all the code you added regarding selection and see what happens. Text should not be selected on default when added to a textbox, read-only property set to true or otherwise. Also check if you have textBox1.Focus() somewhere, this would select all your text.

Comment: Which kind of application? I've tested on asp.net and Windows Forms. I couldn't reproduce your problem.

Comment: @BrunoLM, for winforms at least, if you add a readonly textbox and button to a form, set the text in the button click, then tab to the textbox, all of the text in the textbox will be selected.  I believe this is what the OP is asking about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After you set the text, clear the selection:

```
textBox1.Text += "String" + Environment.NewLine + "String";
textBox1.Select(0, 0);
```

`SelectionLength` will be `0` until after the `TextBox` receives focus, which explains why setting that property did not work.

Answer (score 5):

try

```
textbox1.Enabled = false;
```

Comment: text in that TextBox should be selectable

Comment: @Xaver: Your question clearly says you want to get rid of it; *>>all text inside the text box is selected. **how i can rid that** *.

Comment: @KMan, when the textbox first receives focus, all of the text is selected by default; this initial selection is what he wants to clear.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the ReadOnly property to True should be enough. Maybe you have some other code that selects the text you programtically put into the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

I need a little more information from you. Are you trying to disable the textbox (Read-only)? You can say `"Textbox1.enabled = false"`

Comment: Hi @John, welcome to StackOverflow.  You should ask for more info in comments, not answers.